# how do i extract each format HH:MM-HH:MM into array in js

Tags: javascript, regex, reactjs, format

i have string that looks like this

`"sunday# 00:01 - 23:59?00:01 - 23:59?00:01 - 23:59?00:01 - 23:59"`

its activity hours per day

how do i extract each format`HH:MM - HH:MM` and put all of them into array?
so ill have
 `["23-59 - 00:01","23-59 - 00:01","23-59 - 00:01","23-59 - 00:01"]`

i might receive `"sunday# close"`
or
`"sunday# 00:01 - 23:59"`

i want to extract all activity hours from that string into array cause once i have it in array i print it as table in gui

Comment: A little more explanation is needed here. What do these sub-strings represent, and what is the general format? The example given is a little too ambiguous, and you haven't provided enough context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using just `Array.split` and `Array.map` should do the job for what you want:

```js
    var str = "sunday# 00:01 - 23:59?00:01 - 23:59?00:01 - 23:59?00:01 - 23:59";
var result = str.split("#")[1].trim().split("?");
if(result.length > 1){
    result.map(e=>{var s = e.split("-"); return s[1].trim()+" - "+s[0].trim()});
}
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe this should work for you well !

```js
var str = "sunday# 00:01 - 23:59?00:01 - 23:59?00:01 - 23:59?00:01 - 23:59";

var result = [...str.matchAll(/[0-2]{1}[0-3]{1}:[0-5]{1}[0-9]{1} - [0-2]{1}[0-3]{1}:[0-5]{1}[0-9]{1}/g)];

console.log(result.flat());
```